# Creating a Reminder Workflow which send emails each week

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, email, reminder, scheduled-tasks

I'm about to create a custom workflow for reminding people that their UAT signoff is past due. This could span up to 10 weeks sending an email out each week if we don't get their signoff. Basically, the design is:

- After Week 5 (Created Date > 5 weeks from today), send an email
- After Week 6, if still past due, send reminder email
- After Week 7, if still past due, send reminder email
- send email each week until week 10 hits at which point their site is flagged for deletion.

If I do this in SPD, there could potentially be hundreds of instances running at once, would this be an issue? My alternative thinking was to have a Task Scheduled  that uses CSOM to poll the list every week and send out the email if past due. What are the suggested approaches for sending reminder emails in SPO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this in SPD by looping through the list once a day.  Create a workflow that loops through each item in the list, and sends each email based on the date and then goes to sleep for 23 hours and 49 minutes.

Comment: That way there should only be one instance? Sounds like its worth a try